# gem globalize3 on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile, globalize3, globalize

Someon are using globalize3 with rails4.
How you configure it?

i tryed to install, on my Gemfile:

```
gem 'globalize3', github: 'svenfuchs/globalize3', branch: 'rails4'
```

but i have these errors:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    globalize3 (>= 0) ruby depends on
      railties (~> 3.0) ruby

    coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    globalize3 (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3) ruby

    rails (4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (= 4.0.0) ruby

    simple_form (~> 3.0.0.rc) ruby depends on
      actionpack (4.0.0.rc1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `globalize3` gem has been renamed [`globalize`](http://rubygems.org/gems/globalize) and major version numbers now correspond to the corresponding version of ActiveRecord (3.x for AR3 and 4.x for AR4).

So all you need to do is put this in your Gemfile, and you should not get any conflict:

```
gem 'globalize', '~> 4.0.0.alpha.2'
```

See also the [github repository](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this use these 2 lines at your Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'paper_trail', github: 'airblade/paper_trail', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'globalize3', github: 'svenfuchs/globalize3', branch: 'rails4', ref: 'ffb5c771b9'
```

Comment: thank you. but there are other problems with attribute_accessible and my specific models, I think still waiting for next releases.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Paper_trail merged rails4 into master branch.

```
gem 'globalize3', github: 'svenfuchs/globalize3', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'paper_trail', github: 'airblade/paper_trail', branch: 'master'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`gem 'globalize', '~> 4.0.2'`

Please check on the latest instructions here:

https://github.com/globalize/globalize#installation